# Show that $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right) = \large(-1)^{\frac{p^2-1}{8}\large}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity, legendre-symbol

I'm working on the following problem that is using the Legendre Symbol:

---

Show that $$\left(\frac{2}{p}\right) = \large(-1)^{\frac{p^2-1}{8}\large}$$

---

So I know that $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right) = \left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                     1 &\text{if }\>\>p\equiv\pm1\>\text{ mod }8\\
                  -1 &\text{if }\>\>p\equiv\pm3\>\text{ mod }8
                \end{array}
              \right.$

But I'm not sure how to use this for the proof (assuming it's relevant).

Whether it's $1$ or $-1$ will depend on if the exponent is even or odd.

I'm not sure how to tie that all together. Any pointers?

Comment: For most primes, $p^2$  can't be even… ;o)

Comment: @Bernard "most" made me chuckle

Comment: Ah, right... a bit of an oversight on my part haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just calculate the values of $\dfrac{p^2-1}8$ in both cases:

- if $p=8k\pm 1$, $\dfrac{p^2-1}8=\dfrac{64k^2\pm16k}8=2k(4k\pm1)$ is even,
- if $p=8k\pm 3$, $\dfrac{p^2-1}8=\dfrac{64k^2\pm48k+8}8=2k(4k\pm3)+1$ is odd.

Answer (score 1):

The complicated exponent
$$
\frac{p^2 -1}{8}
$$
is just a somewhat confusing way to express what you say you know about the quadratic character of $2$. You can prove that by checking the four possible cases for $p \pmod 8$.

This is just like using the exponent $n-1$ in the expression $(-1)^{n-1}$ as a way to distinguish between even and odd $n$ - that is, $n \pmod 2$. If you wanted to cover the two odd cases modulo $4$ you could use the exponent $(n-1)/2$.